# Как правильно писать: не обратил внимания или не обратил внимание?

Tags: словообразование

Как правильно писать: не обратил внимания или не обратил внимание?

Answer (score 9):

Вопрос относится к теме переходных глаголов с отрицанием, когда делается выбор между Р.п. и В.п.

Основным падежом в этом случае является Р.п., он же считается более точным (нейтральным по стилю) и имеющим значение подчеркнутого отрицания. В.п. ослабляет отрицание, а также может употребляться в разговорной речи.

(ПОЯСНЕНИЕ. В.п. предполагает полный охват предмета действием, но действие в нашем случае отрицается, поэтому используется Р.п. со значением достижения/недостижения границ предмета).

В приведенном примере можно использовать вариант "не обратил внимания" в качестве основного, а вариант "не обратил внимание" допустим в разговорном стиле.

Интересно также отметить влияние вида глагола: в случае совершенного вида В.п. употребляется чаще, сравнить: не обращать внимания - не обратить внимание.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от контекста, то есть от падежа.
В значении "не заметил": я не обратил внимания. (Родительный падеж.) 
В значении "сделать так, чтобы кто-то заметил": хочу обратить ваше внимание на приведенные примеры. (Винительный п.)

Comment: Не надо править, имхо. Этот ответ настолько плох, что его правкой лучше не сделаешь. Автор подменил управление при отрицании личной формы глагола управлением при инфинитиве. И делает какие-то выводы. Так что не в "творительном п." дело. А в полном непонимании вопроса.